# Proof that $\lim_{x\to 0} {1\over x}$ does not exist.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I've done a proof for the following question. I'm not a mathematician (or a math student) myself, and I don't know anyone who is. Please evaluate my proof and point out any mistake I've done.

Question:

Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0} {1\over x}$ does not exist.

My Solution:

Proof by contradiction: Assume that the limit exists and is some real number L. Then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all x, if $ \lvert x-0\rvert = |x| < \delta$ then $|{1\over x}-L| < \epsilon.$ I will prove that for some such x the latter inequality does not hold. Since $\epsilon$ is any number, take $\epsilon = 1$. Since x is only restricted above, we can take $x < min(\delta,{1\over |L+1|}).$ Then ${1\over x} > |L+1|$.

Since $|{1\over x} - L| > ||L+1|-L|=1,$ then $1 < \epsilon = 1.$, which is a contradiction.

EDIT:

The part where I concluded $|{1\over x} - L| > ||L+1|-L|$ was false. Instead, I've done a proof by cases.

In all cases, $|{1\over x} - L| \ge |{1\over x}| - |L|.$ Therefore $|{1\over x}| - |L| < \epsilon$.

Case 1: L is positive.

We take $x<min(\delta,{1\over |L+1|})$ and $\epsilon = 1$ as did previously. Since ${1\over x} > |L+1|,$ then $ |L+1| - |L| = 1 < |{1\over x}| - |L|<\epsilon=1.$ Hence a contradiction.

Case 2: L is nonpositive.

We take $ x < min(\delta,1).$ Then ${1\over x} >1.$ Since L is nonpositive and ${1\over x} >1,$ we get $|{1\over x} - L| > 1.$ Putting $\epsilon = 1,$ we get a contradiction.

Thus L does not exist in R.

Comment: How did you get $|\frac{1}{x}-L|>||L+1|-L|=1$?

Comment: Thank you, I saw the problem there. I've edited my proof, could you take a look at it again?

Comment: Looks good! Before the edit, you could've used $x<\min (\delta,\frac{1}{|L|+1})$.

Comment: Yeah, that's more clever :) Thanks!

Comment: If you don't require using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs directly, and instead can use the product law, then: $1 = \lim_{x\to 0} 1 = \lim_{x\to 0} x \cdot \frac{1}{x} = \left( \lim_{x\to 0} x \right) \cdot \left( \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x} \right) = 0 \cdot L = 0$, contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to understand $\epsilon - \delta$ proofs better, but this is a fine proof too.